# Run time error on a new ReactJs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Tried to run an ReactJs application but it throws an error , i have already tried with the solution's which i got from the terminal but none of them had worked.

**npm version : 6.7.0 , 
  node : 11.8.0, 
  react: 16.7.0**

And the error is ,

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
```

It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"babel-jest": "23.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

/home/jerold/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 23.4.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if /home/jerold/node_modules/babel-jest is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

Comment: Double check point #6. Did you install babel-jest globally?

Comment: It says to NOT install Babel globally 